# Convert structured notation text to object in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, text

I have a response from an API call that provides me with a form of dot notation text. What I would like to be able to do is to convert the dot notation text into something I can easily manipulate - like an object. The dot notation text is asymmetric so that the 'depth' of the dot notation describing a particular feature is variable. Example text:

```
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Class=Normal
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.Action[0]=Appear
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.Action[1]=Cross
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.DetectRegion[0][0]=764
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.DetectRegion[0][1]=6089
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.DetectRegion[1][0]=2694
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.DetectRegion[1][1]=5991
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.DetectRegion[2][0]=2603
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.DetectRegion[2][1]=7902
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.DetectRegion[3][0]=637
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.DetectRegion[3][1]=7805
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.Direction=Both
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.MaxTargets=15
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.MinDuration=6
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.MinTargets=1
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.ReportInterval=0
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.Sensitivity=5
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.SizeFilter.CalibrateBoxs[0].CenterPoint[0]=4096
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.SizeFilter.CalibrateBoxs[0].CenterPoint[1]=4096
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.SizeFilter.CalibrateBoxs[0].Ratio=1
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.SizeFilter.MaxSize[0]=8191
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.SizeFilter.MaxSize[1]=8191
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.SizeFilter.MinSize[0]=0
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.SizeFilter.MinSize[1]=0
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.SizeFilter.Type=ByLength
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Config.TrackDuration=30
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Enable=true
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.AlarmOutChannels[0]=0
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.AlarmOutEnable=false
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.AlarmOutLatch=10
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.BeepEnable=false
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.Dejitter=0
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.Delay=30
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.ExAlarmOutChannels[0]=0
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.ExAlarmOutEnable=false
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.Enable=false
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.FilckerIntevalTime=5
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.FilckerLightType=RedBlueLight
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.LightDuration=10
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.LightLinkType=Filcker
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[0][0]=1 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[0][1]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[0][2]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[0][3]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[0][4]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[0][5]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[1][0]=1 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[1][1]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[1][2]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[1][3]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[1][4]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[1][5]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[2][0]=1 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[2][1]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[2][2]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[2][3]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[2][4]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[2][5]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[3][0]=1 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[3][1]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[3][2]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[3][3]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[3][4]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[3][5]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[4][0]=1 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[4][1]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[4][2]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[4][3]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[4][4]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[4][5]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[5][0]=1 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[5][1]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[5][2]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[5][3]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[5][4]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[5][5]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[6][0]=1 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[6][1]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[6][2]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[6][3]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[6][4]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LightingLink.WhiteLightTimeSection[6][5]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LogEnable=false
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.LogRemote=true
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.MMSEnable=false
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.MailEnable=true
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.MatrixChannels[0]=0
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.MatrixEnable=false
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.MessageEnable=false
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.PtzLink[0][0]=None
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.PtzLink[0][1]=0
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.PtzLink[0][2]=0
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.PtzLink[0][3]=0
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.PtzLink[0][4]=0
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.PtzLinkEnable=false
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.RecordChannels[0]=0
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.RecordEnable=true
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.RecordLatch=10
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.SnapshotChannels[0]=0
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.SnapshotEnable=true
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.SnapshotPeriod=0
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.SnapshotTimes=1
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.SnapshotTitleEnable=true
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[0][0]=1 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[0][1]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[0][2]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[0][3]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[0][4]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[0][5]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[1][0]=1 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[1][1]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[1][2]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[1][3]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[1][4]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[1][5]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[2][0]=1 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[2][1]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[2][2]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[2][3]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[2][4]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[2][5]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[3][0]=1 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[3][1]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[3][2]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[3][3]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[3][4]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[3][5]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[4][0]=1 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[4][1]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[4][2]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[4][3]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[4][4]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[4][5]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[5][0]=1 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[5][1]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[5][2]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[5][3]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[5][4]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[5][5]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[6][0]=1 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[6][1]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[6][2]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[6][3]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[6][4]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.TimeSection[6][5]=0 00:00:00-23:59:59
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.Voice.AudioFileName=/usr/data/audiofiles/audios/alarm.wav
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.Voice.PlayTimes=3
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].EventHandler.VoiceEnable=false
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Id=1
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Name=Test Rule
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].ObjectTypes[0]=Human
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].ObjectTypes[1]=Vehicle
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].PtzPresetId=0
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].TrackEnable=false
table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][0].Type=CrossRegionDetection
```

This output comes from a CCTV camera. The 'table' might have multiple 'rules' set up on it based on the `[channel number][rule number]` notation that comes before the .Class or .Config etc... For example `table.VideoAnalyseRule[0][1]` would be the second rule on the first channel (counting starts at zero). `table.VideoAnalyseRule[1][0]` would be the second channel, first rule, and so on.....

The objective is to have something that I can use to manipulate the setup of any particular rule, such as say changing the value of Enable from 0 to 1, or changing the name, or the schedule, or the logging, etc..... I would then create the necessary API call(s) to output the data to the target CCTV camera with any changes that were made - the output format is basically JSON if I wish to send commands to the device.

Is there a Python library designed to handle this sort of data? Is there a 'Pythonic' way to handle this type of information? Am I going to need to write a custom parser for this?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to be able to do is to convert the dot notation text into something I can easily manipulate - like an object.

The following code handles the example input. You might need to tweak it if actual input is more general. Also, you may want to customize it, e.g. convert all-digit strings to numbers.

```
import re, json

root = None

def getset_thing_denoted_by(accessor, initial_value):
    # Return the entity denoted by {accessor}.
    # If it doesn't yet exist, ensure that it does,
    # using {initial_value} as its value.

    if (mo := re.fullmatch(r'(\w+)', accessor)):
        # accessing the root

        [root_name] = mo.groups()
        global root
        if root is None:
            root = initial_value

        return root

    elif (mo := re.fullmatch(r'(\S+)\.(\w+)', accessor)):
        # accessing a field of an 'object'

        (object_accessor, field_name) = mo.groups()

        # We represent the object with a dict.
        obj = getset_thing_denoted_by(object_accessor, {})

        # The field might not yet exist
        if field_name not in obj:
            obj[field_name] = initial_value

        return obj[field_name]

    elif (mo := re.fullmatch(r'(\S+)\[(\d+)]', accessor)):
        # accessing an element of an 'array'

        (array_accessor, index_str) = mo.groups()

        # We represent an array as a list.
        arr = getset_thing_denoted_by(array_accessor, [])
        index = int(index_str)

        # The indexed element might not yet exist.
        assert len(arr) in [index, index+1]
        if len(arr) == index:
            arr.append(initial_value)

        assert len(arr) == index+1
        return arr[index]

    else:
        assert 0, f"Can't handle accessor: {accessor}"

for line in open('sample.txt'):
    (lhs, rhs) = re.fullmatch(r'(\S+)=(.+)\n', line).groups()
    getset_thing_denoted_by(lhs, rhs)

print(json.dumps(root, indent=4))
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for sharing this. I will give it a crack.

Cheers

The Frog